# how to create patches with few changes

Tags: windows-installer, patch

I´m trying to build patches for my application using vs2010. I used these tutorials:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/visualstudionetadd-ins/article.php/c9663

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=11373

But I get an error with code 0xC00E5114. The resulting log says: ERROR: UpgradedImages.MsiPath 'c:\project\setup2\' does not exist. It's supposed that this path contains the updated msi. How to solve this??

I used this method because I just make few changes and don't wanna buy tools like installshield (excellent, but expensive). Or does anybody know another method or tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all blank in your filename. Msimsp.exe likes short name (test.msi for example).

Answer (score 0):

In your pcp file, update UpgradedImages folder by changing the MsiPath to full filePath **'c:\project\setup2\urMsi.msi** instead of using just the folder path.